# Maths Probability

Tags: c#, probability

What is the probability of getting a 10 or a 11 when a pair of dice are rolled?

How to do

Comment: How many combinations are possible (100%)? How many of these possible combinations give you the desired values (n%)? Now, do a rule of three.

Comment: Wolfram alpha doesn't seem to cope with that sort of query very well

Comment: @Tom: try informing "2 dices = 10", and "2 dices = 11", then sum the results ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 36 possible rolls (6*6).

On the first dice, a 4, 5 or 6 will give you a roll that can provide a valid solution.

So, here is a list of rolls that are valid:

```
    D1    D2    Result
    ------------------
    4     6     10
    5     6     11
    5     5     10
    6     4     10
    6     5     11
```

Total of 5 solutions from 36.

(5/36)*100 = 13.9%

or

5/36 = 10/72 and 10/72 = 1/7.2

If you were a betting man, you would offer someone 1:6 they can't throw this number, or 1:8 that you can throw the number :)

Comment: =] Correct Thanks.
What i did was an extra :
D1   D2
5     5
5     5

I tot the order was important in this qn =/

Answer (score 4):

With die one across the top and die 2 down the left you can see that there is a possible 
5 out of 36 (which is 6 x 6) chance.

```
    1  2  3  4   5   6 
1   2  3  4  5   6   7
2   3  4  5  6   7   8
3   4  5  6  7   8   9
4   5  6  7  8   9   10
5   6  7  8  9   10  11
6   7  8  9  10  11  12
```

The probability of a particular combination is 1 in 36 Because 5 combinations add to 10 or 11 it makes it 5/36 or 0.139.

Comment: haha yes.  I wrote it as 5/36 though. Thanks for poitning it out

Comment: Thanks - I fat fingered that - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. Count how many combinations lead to the expected result and divide through 36.